# Combinatorial interpretation for Möbius-poly-Bernoulli numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, analytic-number-theory, bernoulli-numbers

The [Möbius-Bernoulli numbers](https://www.degruyter.com/view/journals/math/17/1/article-p32.xml) ,are related to Dedekind Sums

$$\sum_{d|n}\frac{t\mu(d)}{e^{td}-1}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty M_k(n)\frac{t^k}{k!}$$ where $|t|<\frac{2\pi}{n}$, and $M_k(1)=B_k$.

We define the Möbius-poly-Bernoulli numbers as

$$\sum_{d|n}\frac{Li_m(1-e^{-t\mu(d)})}{1-e^{-td}}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty M_k^{(m)}(n)\frac{t^k}{k!}$$

Is there a combinatorial interpretation for Möbius-poly-Bernoulli numbers.

Poly-Bernoulli numbers introduced by Kaneko
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poly-Bernoulli_number

Poly-Bernoulli numbers of negative index enumerate the set of $n$ by $k$  $(0,1)-$matrices uniquely reconstructible from their row and column sums.

Riemann Hypothesis is related to Möbius functions. One of ways to solve RH is using generating functions. I think Möbius-poly-Bernoulli numbers must be a suitable generating functions. See [Sarnak lecture](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://publications.ias.edu/sites/default/files/Mahler%2520Colloquium%2520Lecture%25204%2520-Mobius%2520randomness%2520and%2520dynamics.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwi_t4jDhcXrAhVqhosKHWXNAq4QFjAAegQIAhAB&usg=AOvVaw2Tw6iW46wpvQNmvVHRQnAH)